# Code to import data from a Stack overflow query into R

Tags: r

When I try to answer a question in Stack Overflow about R, a good part of my time is spent trying to rebuild the data given as example (unless the question author has been nice enough to provide them as R code).

So my question is, if somebody just asks a question and gives his sample data frame the following way :

```
a  b   c
1 11 foo
2 12 bar
3 13 baz
4 14 bar
5 15 foo
```

Do you have a tip or a function to import this easily into an R session, without having to type the entire `data.frame()` instruction ?

Thanks in advance for any hint !

PS : sorry if the term "query" is not really nice in my question title, but it seems you can't use the word "question" in a question title in Stack overflow :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe `textConnection()` is what you want here:

```
R> zz <- read.table(textConnection("a  b   c
1 11 foo
2 12 bar
3 13 baz
4 14 bar
5 15 foo"), header=TRUE)
R> zz
  a  b   c
1 1 11 foo
2 2 12 bar
3 3 13 baz
4 4 14 bar
5 5 15 foo
R>
```

It allows you to treat the text as a "connection" from which to read.  You can also just copy and paste, but access from the clipboard is more dependent on the operating system and hence less portable.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's great, thanks ! Access from the clipboard works nicely on my system with `zz <- read.table(file(description="clipboard"), header=TRUE)`

Comment: @juba, `read.table` also offers a `text` argument, so that creating the connection isn't necessary. `read.table(text = "a  b   c...` should work, too. Nice with the clipboard!

Comment: @juba Note that the clipboard afaik doesn't work on all systems. I believe (but correct me if I'm wrong) that it is Windows specific.

Comment: It works well on my linux system. There is a "clipboard" section in the `connections` man page, with detailed informations : if I understand correctly, reading and writing to the clipboard works under windows, reading works out of the box under linux, whereas writing on linux and reading/writing on Mac OSX requires specific calls to `pipe()`.

Comment: For the Mac (where `?clipboard` takes you to the connections help page): "Mac OS X users can use pipe("pbpaste") and pipe("pbcopy", "w") to read from and write to that system's clipboard." Effective use would be: `zz<- read.table(file=pipe("pbpaste"), header=TRUE)`

Answer (score 24):

Recent version of R now offer an even lower keystroke option than the `textConnection` route for entry of columnar data into read.table and friends. faced with this:

```
zz
  a  b   c
1 1 11 foo
2 2 12 bar
3 3 13 baz
4 4 14 bar
5 5 15 foo
```

One can simply insert : `<- read.table(text="` after the `zz`, delete the carriage-return and then insert `", header=TRUE)` after the last `foo` and type [enter].

```
zz<- read.table(text="  a  b   c
1 1 11 foo
2 2 12 bar
3 3 13 baz
4 4 14 bar
5 5 15 foo", header=TRUE)
```

One can also use `scan` to efficiently enter long sequences of pure numbers or pure character vector entries. Faced with: 67  75  44  25  99  37   6  96  77  21  31  41   5  52  13  46  14  70 100  18 , one can simply type: `zz <- scan()` and hit [enter]. Then paste the selected numbers and hit [enter] again and perhaps a second time to cause a double carriage-return and the console should respond "read 20 items".

```
> zz <- scan()
1: 67  75  44  25  99  37   6  96  77  21  31  41   5  52  13  46  14  70 100  18
21: 
Read 20 items
```

The "character" task. after pasting to console and editing out extraneous line-feeds and adding quotes, then hitting [enter]:

```
> countries <- scan(what="character")
1:     'republic of congo'
2:     'republic of the congo'
3:     'congo, republic of the'
4:     'congo, republic'
5: 'democratic republic of the congo'
6: 'congo, democratic republic of the'
7: 'dem rep of the congo'
8: 
Read 7 items
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also ask the questioner to use [the `dput` function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/dput.html) which dumps any data structure in a way that can be just copy-pasted into R. e.g.

```
> zz
  a  b   c
1 1 11 foo
2 2 12 bar
3 3 13 baz
4 4 14 bar
5 5 15 foo

> dput(zz)
structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 11:15, c = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("bar", "baz", "foo"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

> xx <- structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 11:15, c = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 
+ 1L, 3L), .Label = c("bar", "baz", "foo"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("a", 
+ "b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
> xx
  a  b   c
1 1 11 foo
2 2 12 bar
3 3 13 baz
4 4 14 bar
5 5 15 foo
```

Answer (score 5):

Just want to add this because I now use it regularly and I think it's quite useful.  There is a package *overflow* (install instructions below) that has a function to read copied data frames. Say I begin with an SO post that contains the data shown as the following, but with no `dput` output.

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Now if I copy that data directly, and then run the following

```
library(overflow)
soread()
# data.frame “mydf” created in your workspace
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

I now have a data frame named `mydf` identical to the one I copied in my global environment, so I don't have to wait for the OP to post a `dput` of their data frame.  I can change the name of the data frame with the `out` argument, which (obviously) defaults to `mydf`.  There are also a few other useful functions for working with SO posts in the package (like `sopkgs()`, which installs a package temporarily so you can help with a question about a package that you have not previously installed).

If you leave `library(overflow)` in your `.Rprofile`, then `soread()` makes pretty quick work of importing data from SO posts.

*overflow* is available from GitHub, and can be installed with

```
library(devtools)
install_github("overflow", "sebastian-c")
```