# Quick way to turn copied text to character strings in R?

Tags: r, string, function, character, shortcut

I have a list of text that I copied from outside of R:

- Ex: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j

I want to just quickly turn each word (in this case letter) to a character string for R to use:

- Ex: 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'

**Is there a function or quick way to turn external text into string characters?**

Example:

```
> a,b,c,d
Error: unexpected ',' in "a,"

> function(a,b,c,d)
[1] 'a','b','c','d'
```

I understand a simple function likely won't work because it will assume the non-character strings are unknown R objects. But there is likely some trick to make this work?

Note: I know I can do this in other programs (e.g., notepad ++) fairly quickly, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do so quickly in R?

Comment: You can use `scan` i.e. `scan(text='a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j',what = "", sep=",", quiet=TRUE)` .  If it is stored in a file `scan("yourfile.txt", what ="", sep=",", quiet=TRUE)`

Comment: `f <- function(..., simplify = TRUE) sapply(eval(substitute(alist(...))), function(x) if (is.symbol(x)) as.character(x) else eval(x), simplify = simplify); f(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)` works with other things `f(a, one = 1, two, x = rnorm(10))`

Comment: You would also  need `strip.white = TRUE` in `scan()`.

Comment: @RichScriven Good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy solution using `read.table` and the clipboard (as seen [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/copying-data-from-excel-to-r-and-back/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438556/how-do-i-copy-and-paste-data-into-r-from-the-clipboard#)):

1. Copy text or data to clipboard.
2. Use the following code:

   ```
   read.table("clipboard", head = T, sep = z)
   ```

   - where z is `","` for comma delimited, `"\t"` for tab delimited, etc.

---

Using `scan` is a good alternative as well:

```
scan(text='a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j',what = "", sep=",", quiet=TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

(from comments by akrun and Rich Scriven).

---

The read.table method is quicker and maintains the structure of the text if its a table with headings (e.g., text copied from MS Excel). So if you're copying data with structure, use `read.table`.

If you're simply copying text (especially if you just want to copy it directly into your script), then the scan method is sufficient and "more transparent."

Comment: Note that the "clipboard" string in `read.table` will only work in Windows.

Comment: @Gregor: Thanks. Being a strictly Windows user I had no idea. Do you know a work around for non-Windows users? I'll update my answer accordingly...

Comment: My work computer recently switched to a Mac so it's fresh in my mind ;) The best I've found is using the `text` argument for `read.table` as you show with `scan`, just pasting into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something simple:

I first copy `a,b,c,d` and in `R`:

```
z <- readClipboard()
z
[1] "a,b,c,d"
```

Then you can play around with it. Example:

```
strsplit(z, split = ",")
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

*EDIT:* This will only work on Windows. Thanks for comment @Gregor.

Comment: I don't know why others are putting answers only in comments.

Comment: It is silly but I've been guilty of doing that at times. Typically it's because either 1) I didn't feel what I wrote was elaborated enough to be considered a full "answer" or 2) I haven't actually tested the solution.

Comment: I had this ambiguity I felt that my answer was elaborated enough to answer the question but hardly more elaborated or better than those in the comments.

Comment: You're doing the right thing.  Even in those cases I mention typically writing an answer is more appropriate than a comment but some of us opt to go the comment route because it's safer or we're lazy and don't want to provide an answer we don't 100% stand behind.  Answers are the right way to go though so you did the right thing.