# Save numbers from R to excel

Tags: r

I need to now how can I export data from r to excel but used \n
Ineed save numbers one by one row by row.

Example:

1234

3233

4543

Comment: Assuming that you have the numbers in an array `x = c(1234, 3233, 4543)` just use `write.table(x, "Output.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)`

Comment: I removed the [tag:rstudio] tag, since that is for issues with the RStudio IDE, not the R programming language. If I'm incorrect in this, please edit your question and give more context. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to save to a file, use `write.csv` or `write.table`. If you want them whole line-by-line (as in not columns), you can use `writeLines`, but that's not really specific to Excel. If you just need a quick "get this data into Excel" and don't need to save the file, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13438556/3358272.

Comment: @G5W, the default `sep=` for `write.table` is a space, which isn't technically CSV. This causes Excel to put each row in a single cell. I'd suggest either `write.csv` or `write.table(..., sep=",")` (which is almost the same).

Comment: @r2evans The OP asks for a single column of numbers.  The separator is not really relevant.