# readLines unknown n

Tags: r

While in a gui (be it Windows gui or RStudio etc) I can use `readLines` from a script with a known number of lines as seen below by specifying `n=?`.  What if I am unsure of the number of lines being read (i.e., I have a lot of lines and don't know n).  How can I use `readLines` in a gui (read from a script within not an outside file) without specifying n?  If you don't supply n it appears `readLines` keeps the connection open and keeps on reading lines.  Hitting esc stops the function but no lines are read.

```
x <- readLines(n=4)
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices

x
```

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpM3vRCSDk0&feature=youtu.be) demoing the specific problem I am asking.

This is particularly useful when a poster gives you data in an odd format like the set below and you want to read it in without counting all the rows:

```
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
```

**EDIT** Until this gets reopened and Dason can answer himself...

Dason suggests using ctrl + z and this works (at least on a Windows machine)

Comment: You don't need to specify the number of lines. It keeps reading until the connection stops supplying.

Comment: How do I stop the connection from reading then?

Comment: It reads to the end of the file. (I must be missing a crucial bit of perspective. You are able to open a connection to an edit buffer?)

Comment: Yes that works nicely with an external .R/.txt file but what about reading select lines from a script within something like RStudio.  it just keeps reading lines.

Comment: Have you tried control-D?

Comment: Just did, no dice.  I am uploading a video to youtube to share to demo the problem more clearly as I think I'm not expressing the issue properly.

Comment: Voting to close without a statement of why or a downvote is unhelpful.  To the downvoter and closers did you look at the video?

Comment: In the windows GUI shown in the video, I had luck with Ctrl-z

Comment: @TylerRinker Maybe they just think you're a horrible creature made of concentrated hatred and deserve to have imaginary internet points taken away.  Just sayin' ;)

Comment: I was saving up my points to buy a new car.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code to import data from a Stack overflow query into R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849270/code-to-import-data-from-a-stack-overflow-query-into-r)

Comment: @GSee that is a typically formatted dataframe the question specifically says `an odd format`

Comment: Since I can't add an actual answer anymore - ctrl+z does what Tyler wants to do (at least on Windows)

Comment: On Mac or Linux, ctrl + z immediately terminates the R session. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Two easy solutions.

1. Put the text into another file, and read that.
2. Don't use `readLines`.  Quote the text:

```
x <- strsplit("** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
", "\n")


x
[[1]]
[1] "** preparing package for lazy loading" "** help"                               "*** installing help indices"          
[4] "** building package indices"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap quotes around the text and create a `textConnection` to read

```
text <- "** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices"

readLines(textConnection(text))
# [1] "** preparing package for lazy loading" "** help"                              
# [3] "*** installing help indices"           "** building package indices"          
# [5] "** preparing package for lazy loading" "** help"                              
# [7] "*** installing help indices"           "** building package indices"          
# [9] "** preparing package for lazy loading" "** help"                              
#[11] "*** installing help indices"           "** building package indices"          
#[13] "** preparing package for lazy loading" "** help"                              
#[15] "*** installing help indices"           "** building package indices"          
#[17] "** preparing package for lazy loading" "** help"                              
#[19] "*** installing help indices"           "** building package indices"
```

Comment: I think this is closest to the spirit of what I was trying to accomplish with the least amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

In a Windows environment after selecting and copying to the clipboard:

```
 (clip.input <- readLines( file("clipboard") ) )
```

In a Mac/UNIX:

```
 (clip.input <- readLines( pipe("pbpaste") ) )
```