# Copy and paste data into R

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I copy and paste data into R? For example, you see a small data set on the web, perhaps in a blog or here on StackOverflow, and you want that data set in your R session. This is a common task for many of us, and there are several ways to go about. Below I present a solution based on [this blog post](http://www.magesblog.com/2012/03/copy-and-paste-small-data-sets-into-r.html) that I have found useful.

This question has of course been asked before, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438556/how-do-i-copy-and-paste-data-into-r-from-the-clipboard) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849270/code-to-import-data-from-a-stack-overflow-query-into-r) however, these posts are rather old and overcrowded which makes finding a short working answer difficult.

Comment: So you think having even more questions asking the same thing will make it easier for future readers to find answers? My suggestion: instead of promoting the dup, delete your version and upvote the most helpful answers elsewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, copy (e.g. "⌘ + C") the data set.

Then, paste (e.g. "⌘ + V") to create an R character vector:

`x <- "   A B C D
 1: 2 2 5 3
 2: 2 1 2 3
 3: 3 4 4 3"`

Next, use the `read.table()` function:

```
y <- read.table(text = x, header = TRUE)
```

Done! The data is now in a data frame:

```
class(y)
[1] "data.frame"
```

You might also want to check out the `dput()` function which writes an ASCII text representation of an R object that you can paste into your StackOverflow question or answer.