# How to transform a dataframe console output to its structure automatically

Tags: r, reprex

Unexperienced users of StackOverflow tend to provide console output of the data they use:

```
  id name
1  1 john
2  2 mary
```

Users with more experience should encourage them to provide a [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or to use `dput` to provide  data structure, but they don't always have time.
Do you know of a package/function allowing **to copy the console output of a dataframe** and to **generate out of the clipboard the associated structure**?

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2), name = c("john", "mary")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

To make it short, I'm looking for and inverted `dput`.
The `reprex` package allows this kind of manipulation, for example [clean-up console output](https://rdrr.io/cran/reprex/man/un-reprex.html), but I didn't find in it the function I'm looking for!

Comment: Related: [Code to import data from a Stack overflow query into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849270/code-to-import-data-from-a-stack-overflow-query-into-r). Just wrap answers in `dput`, I think. You should also read the FAQ [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), where you find  `dput(read.table("clipboard",sep="",header=TRUE))`

Comment: Doesn't really answer you question I guess, but you can also take a look at the `datapasta` package: https://github.com/milesmcbain/datapasta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `read.table`.

```
x <- "
  id name
1  1 john
2  2 mary
"

fun <- function(x, header=TRUE) dput(read.table(header=header, text=x))
fun(x)
# structure(list(id = 1:2, name = c("john", "mary")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
# "2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myVar <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2), name = c("john", "mary")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: how did you create this structure?

Comment: The structure comes from `dput`.  I copied the structure from your post.

Comment: what I'm looking for is to copy the console output of the data itself, and get the structure out of it